# How to make a field in access show the current value in the table, and accept input, but not update the table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been tasked with designing an Access front end for a SQL database I built. Unfortunately my VBA and Access knowledge are not as strong as they should be and I have run into a roadblock.

Currently I'm working on a script that will identify and flag high dollar assets that are entered into the database through the form. I have the update code written, but when I enter in a high value in the field the act of updating the value in the form and the update script itself clash and there is a 'Write Conflict'.

I can unbind the field in the form and that resoles the write conflict, but then the user first browsing to the record won't see the current value in the table.

**My question**: is there a way to have a field in a form show the value in a table, accept input, but not write the input to the table and leave the writing to the update query. If it helps I have included the update action I have written.

```
Private Sub Cost_AfterUpdate()

    Dim CostCheck As String
    CostCheck = "Update dbo_Purchasing SET Capitolasset =  -1, COST = " &       Me.Cost & " " & _
                "Where itemMaster = " & Me.ItemMaster & " and " & Me.Cost & " >= " & 5000 & ""

    DoCmd.RunSQL CostCheck
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: The database update doesn't take place until the active record on the form changes, right? Can you add VBA that updates all the other fields in your SQL statement *on the form* (not in the database, yet) and then allow the form manager to actually update the underlying record at the correct time?

Comment: I've been toying with that idea, but I'm not sure how that would look. Like I said VBA is not my strong suit. So far I've gotten away with using SQL language in VBA, but this seems like it would be structured differently. Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: You need to learn VBA if you want a robust front-end. I have many desktop apps running in Access and there's no way to avoid writing some code. Lots of code.

Comment: why do you want to  update the table again? your form does this automatically for you?

Comment: The field that I am wanting to update is meant to be automatically calculated and populated when the user enters a  high value item in the 'Cost' field. The query I wrote worked just with a write conflict. nicomp sparked a thought though and I figured out the solution. I needed to add 'me.dirty = false' prior to the update statement to get access to ignore the first update and take the second. After I did this it runs perfectly.

Comment: If `Capitolasset`is not changed later, you can just calculate it in the forms query. `SELECT Cost >= 5000 as Capitolasset, COST  FROM dbo_Purchasing` or use a table trigger (`dbo_`suggest that Sql Server is used) . if you store the treshold (5000) in a table or constant it is easy to change for all occurencies.

Comment: @computerVersteher , yep, it's a normalization problem. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to set the `Capitolasset` flag of the current record to `-1` if the `Cost` entered is `>= 5000`. If so, you don't need to run an extra query, just update the `Capitolasset` value according to the `Cost` entered:

```
Private Sub Cost_AfterUpdate()

    If IsNumeric(Me.Cost) Then
        If Me.Cost >= 5000 Then
            Me.Capitolasset = -1
        Else
            Me.Capitolasset = 0
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This will update the field before the record is saved.

Comment: This is a great solution, and much less clunky than using the 'me.dirty' command in front of my SQL script thank you!